# Interior Point Method(Path following) vs Simplex

Tags: linear-programming

What are pros and cons of these two LP methods ? 
I can only think of less iterations in Interior Point Method (when LPP is sufficiently large).

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to list some features of both algorithms to explain what differentiates them.

**Simplex**

- provides a basic solution, useful for branch and bound solvers in integer programming
- easy to warm (or hot) start from a suboptimal solution, also necessary for integer programming
- very high iteration speed mainly due to preservation of sparse data structures, but sometimes requires many iterations to reach optimality
- memory efficient
- numerically very stable

**Interior Point**

- iteration count independent of problem size
- often faster to reach optimality
- easier to parallelize (Cholesky factorization)

In summary, IPM is the way to go for pure LPs, while for reoptimization-heavy applications like (mixed) integer programming the Simplex is better suited. One may also combine both approaches and perform a Simplex-like *cross-over* after the IPM found an optimal solution to get a basic one.

Often, it is a good idea to try both methods and decide then what works best, because performance is very much problem dependent.